# SQL Server data export to mysql using SSIS

Tags: mysql, sql-server, ssis, odbc

I'm trying to export data from SQL Server to MySQL using ODBC and I get an error while trying to form a destination point on SSIS.

What seems to be the problem? The table exists in MySQL

[image]

UPDATE I have found that the problem is the missing license key because i am using MySQL Provider [MySQL Provider Cherry](https://cherrycitysoftware.com/Products/MySQLProvider)

Does anyone know any free alternatives for MySQL Providers using SSIS Ole Db? I know that ADO .Net has it, but is there an Ole Db free alternative?

Comment: do you actually have the ODBC driver installed for MySQL it's saying it can't connect, and that would be the first thing I would look at.

https://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/odbc/

Comment: Yes it is installed and i figured out that this error is because the license key is missing. Are there free alternatives to include mysql in in SSIS Using OleDB?